# Using "I'm fine" when answering with a "thank you"

Tags: word-meaning

Imagine this dialog:

> Do you want a tea?
>
> No, thank you, I'm fine.

Is the use of "I'm fine" irrelevant here? If not, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means "I am fine with what I have", that is, "I need nothing more".

It should be taken in context as a weak protestation, "Not only don't I want a tea, I don't want any other beverages you might think to offer me."

Comment: A very common alternate that means the same thing is "I'm good."

Comment: @DJMcMayhem also, "I'm all set".